# ProtocolException with WCF Service

Tags: wcf, sharepoint, project-server

When I try to access WCF client, I get the following error. I was able to access my service using IE and able to reference in VS 2010. My development environment is Windows server 2008. I hosted service in Sharepoint Project server. I am stuck with this error. Please advice.

"The content type text/html; charset=UTF-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. "

Here is some data Headers from Fiddler.

GET /_vti_bin/psi/helloservice.svc HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8

MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 14.0.0.4762
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-SharePointHealthScore: 4

Answer (score 1):

WCF HTTP Activation must be enabled on the server. If the script maps for WCF are not installed you may receive the error.

Comment: I looked at WCF HTTP Activation. It's already installed. What is the script map? Where can I check it?

Comment: I checked here. Administrator\Server Manager\ Add Features. WCF HTTP Activation is installed.